# How does Object.assign work anyway?

Tags: javascript, assign

I'm trying to change the field in the array. I used `find` function to get the object and then I used `Object.assign` to overwrite the value from the array.

However, in one case it works:

`Object.assign(item2,  {id:3, name: "Do"});`

and in the other case, it doesn't:

`item = Object.assign({}, {id:3, name: "Do"});`

What's different for those two cases?

```js
let arr = [{id:1, name:"John"}, {id:2, name: "Doe"}];
let item = arr.find((x)=> x.id === 2);

//the array is not changed!
item = Object.assign({}, {id:3, name: "Do"});
console.log(arr);

let item2 = arr.find((x)=> x.id === 2);
//the array is changed!
Object.assign(item2,  {id:3, name: "Do"});
console.log(arr);
```

Source: http://jsbin.com/mametudemo/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: You are overwriting `item` when you do `item = Object...` so `item` is no longer part of the array.

Comment: Per the docs - 'The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.' - I guess it is not really clear, because it says returns the target object, not the original reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

`let item = arr.find((x)=> x.id === 2);`

and

`let item2 = arr.find((x)=> x.id === 2);`

In both cases the variables are a "reference" to the same object, the object contained inside the array `arr`. That means that if you change any of them, the changes are reflected into the others (even in the array) because they actually refer to exact same object.

Now, you modify the two variables in two different ways. In this case

`Object.assign(item2,  {id:3, name: "Do"});`

You're merging the new values into `item2`, and because it is a reference, the changes are reflected into the array.

In the second case:

`item = Object.assign({}, {id:3, name: "Do"});`

You're merging the new values in a brand new object (the first parameter of assign `{}`) and then you *overwrite* the variable `item` with it. Now `item` is no longer a reference to the object inside the array. It is a new object, and consequently the object inside the array is not touched.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you create a new object and assign it to `item`. `arr[1]` does not change because you have not used the reference to it, like

```
arr[1] = Object.assign({}, { id: 3, name: "Do" });
```

With the second approach, you take the object and change the properties with the given object.

```js
let arr = [{ id: 1, name: "John" }, { id: 2, name: "Doe" }];
let item = arr.find((x) => x.id === 2);

item = Object.assign({}, { id: 3, name: "Do" });
console.log(arr);                                // the array is not changed!

let item2 = arr.find((x) => x.id === 2);
Object.assign(item2, { id: 3, name: "Do" });
console.log(arr);                                // the array is changed!
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what happens. You find `item`:

```
let item = arr.find((x)=> x.id === 2);
```

At this point `item` is a *reference* to corresponding array element. When you later do assignment:

```
item = Object.assign({}, {id:3, name: "Do"});
```

you overwrite value of the `item` (previously it was a reference) to a new object, which is not a reference to original array anymore. Hence array is not affected.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo/error in your code causing it to not work.

The first time you attempt to change the object you use `item = Object.assign({}, {id:3, name: "Do"});`. Notice the `{}` as the first param to `Object.assign`... that should be `item`.

```js
let arr = [{id:1, name:"John"}, {id:2, name: "Doe"}];

let item = arr.find((x)=> x.id === 2);
//the array is not changed!
Object.assign(item, {id:3, name: "Do"});
console.log(arr);

let item2 = arr.find((x)=> x.id === 3);
//the array is changed!
Object.assign(item2,  {id:3, name: "Doa"});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: That was not a typo, but by design. I wanted to understand why one approach works and the other doesn't.

Comment: Once I saw the other solutions I realized I may have misinterpreted your approach.

Answer (score 0):

First argument of `Object.assign` is `target`.

This is used to append properties and then reference of same object are returned.

So in first case, properties are added to an existing object `item2`. But if you assign this to a variable to say `temp` and do `temp.id = 10`, this will also change in `item2`

To avoid this, `item = Object.assign({}, {id:3, name: "Do"});` is used. This will copy all properties in a blank object and return its reference. So basically you have copied object and not just reference.