# setState nested object using es6 spread

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have default state like this:

```
this.state = {
  location:{
    lat: 1234,
    lng: 3245
  }
}
```

so every time I want to update either lat or lng I have to do this

`this.setState({ location: {...this.state.location, lat: newLate} })`

or

`this.setState({ location: {...this.state.location, lng: newLng } })`

if I have several setState in my component I have to write a lot of `...`, worse if I have one level of nested object to work with. Also it's dangerous to do this `{this.state.location.lat}` because it will have error and it make the whole app to crash if location is not defined. What's the tip when you work on multiple nested array of object or object in react?

Comment: `multiple nested array` - but ... there is no array

Comment: @JaromandaX I did mentioned `or`

Comment: the tip is that `...` makes the code more compact already, how short do you want the code to be?

Comment: @JaromandaX I think there are some library like normlizr to solve this problem.

Comment: well, then use such a library

Comment: When you are dealing with complex states, it becomes harder to debug them as time goes by. You might want to look into using Redux or Mobx for state management.

Answer (score 6):

Whenever possible, keep your state as 'flat' as possible.

In your case, you can simply do:

```
this.state = {
  lat: 1234,
  lng: 3245
}
```

As your state becomes bigger, use naming to segregate the different properties

```
this.state = {
  locationLat: 1234,
  locationLng: 3245
}
```

Even in applications with hundreds of components, I never need to use nested states.

Additional remarks:

- Split your component into smaller pieces whenever you see this pattern
- Only use a nested object if you know the entire object will be updated each time

From your location object:

```
const location = {
    lat: 1234,
    lng: 3245
}
```

initialize your state like so:

```
this.state = location
```

Comment: sometime you can't do whatever you want, I'm a frontend who doesn't have control over the structure of the response data, done by another team.

Comment: but you are free to transform the response into whatever object you want to use in your component.

Comment: edited my post. If thats not what you asked for, please update you question with more details on what your API response actually is or post a new question so as not to be too confusing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is always recommended to keep the state **flat** as possible. So In your case it can be

```
state={
  locationLat:123,
  locationLng: 456,
}
```

The main reason of it comes from [How object.assign works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42021368/how-does-object-assign-work-anyway). It copy the value for only first level.

See the native implementation of [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to understand more. Since it copy only for first level it is recommended to keep state flat.

```js
var a = {b:1, c:{d:1}}

var e = Object.assign({},a)

console.log(a===e) // It will false

e.c.d = 2

console.log(a.c.d) //It will be 2
```

Ref to Read more:

- [State Normalising](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-normalizing-the-state-shape) by Dan